# Reformatting map values and updating with spread syntax

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, lodash, spread-syntax

I'm trying to format the object properties within an array. I'm having some trouble as The following code throws the following error but the react native throws  `TypeError: In this environment the sources for assign MUST be an object.This error is a performance optimization and not spec compliant. <<< path/to/project/node_modules/react-native/packager/src/Resolver/polyfills/polyfills.js`

```
const objArr = [ 
   { event.date: '2016-03-10T00:00:00', event.location: 'NV' },
   { event.date: '2016-03-10T00:00:00', event.location: 'WV' },
   { event.date: '2016-03-10T00:00:00', event.location: 'CA' } 
],

const formatDate = (data) => {
  const formattedDate = moment(data['event.start_date']).format('DD MMM YYYY');

  return { ...data, data['event.start_date']: formattedDate } };
}

const formatDates = (arr) => { return _.map(arr, formatDate) }

let result = _.map(objArr, formatDates);
```

How would i change the `event.date` to the formatted data without touching the rest of the object? In reality have many variables I would like to pass over, and don't think individually assigning each to a new object is best.

How should I go about this? Any help / tips appreciated!

Comment: The sample object you posted doesn't make much sense to me. Does objArr look like `[ { "event": { "date": "2016-03-10T00:00:00", "location": "NV" } } ]` or does it look like `[ { "event.date": "2016-03-10T00:00:00", "event.location": "NV" } ]`?

Comment: They're not nested, the dot notion is just a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be grossly overcomplicating the task by using several `map`s.

If you simplify the problem, you should be able to do this:

```
const objArr = [ 
  { 'event.date': '2016-03-10T00:00:00', 'event.location': 'NV' },
  { 'event.date': '2016-03-10T00:00:00', 'event.location': 'WV' },
  { 'event.date': '2016-03-10T00:00:00', 'event.location': 'CA' } 
];

const result = objArr.map((event) => ({
  ...event,
  'event.start_date': moment(event['event.start_date']).format('DD MMM YYYY'),
}));

console.log(result);
```